# Can onCreate method be called multiple times when there is no configuration changes?

Tags: android

onCreate() method for one of my Activities is being called multiple times and consistently about once every second. I checked the documentation and it says that configuration changes may cause such behavior. I checked for configuration changes using the following code:

on manifest file I added:

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|touchscreen|mnc|mcc|density|uiMode|fontScale|orientation|keyboard|layoutDirection|locale|navigation|smallestScreenSize|keyboardHidden|colorMode|screenSize"
```

On the activity I added:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(@NotNull Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        Log.i(TAG, "onConfigurationChanged: "+newConfig);
    }
```

The method onConfigurationChanged is never called which gave me the impression that configuration is never changed. I am not sure what's causing the "onCreate" and "onDestroy" calls. What could be the possible reasons?

[Sorry for not sharing the rest of the code. I am looking for some generic answers on what could cause the onCreate and onDestroy methods be called except for explicit user interaction]

Edit:

Activity is being started only once and I am not explicitly calling onCreate anywhere in the code.

```
public static void startActivity(Activity activity, Intent intent, int...anim) {
        Log.i(TAG, "startActivity: activity started"); //prints only once
        if (intent == null) {
            intent = new Intent();
        }
        intent.setClass(activity, <My Activity Name>.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        if (anim != null && anim.length > 1) {
            activity.overridePendingTransition(anim[0], anim[1]);
        }
        activity.finish();
    }
```

Comment: Without code it hardly can be resolved. Because you don't make configuration changes, it won't be called more than once. So, you call the activity several times and maybe finish, I don't know.

Comment: Are you calling `startActivity` somewhere like `onResume` or `onCreate` that would cause it to load repeatedly? Having it run every second is definitely not normal or good.

Answer (score 0):

> Can onCreate method be called multiple times when there is no configuration changes?

Only if your activity is being started repeatedly, or you are somehow trying to call `onCreate()` yourself.

Comment: Activity is being started only once, I am not explicitly calling onCreate from anywhere in the code.